# How to add all class properties along with the values to Hashable in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable

I have below 2 model classes:

```
public class InitiateRequest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string FormCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public InitiateFormField Fields { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class InitiateFormField
{
    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("STD_INCIDENTTYPEID")]
    public string IncidentTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string STD_SUBJECTTYPEID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string STD_SUBJECTID { get; set; }

    public string STD_PARENTSUBJECTID { get; set; }

    public int PREPARER_ID { get; set; }

    public string EXISTING_FORMER_CLIENT { get; set; }
    public string MATTER_TITLE { get; set; }
    public string MATTER_DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    public int SUBMITTING_ATTORNEY { get; set; }
    public int NEW_MATTER_RESPONSIBLE_ATTORNEY { get; set; }
    public string MATTER_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string MATTER_PRACTICE_CODE { get; set; }
    public string NEW_CLIENT_CODE { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add all the properties from `InitiateFormField` class to a Hashtable.
`var properties = new Hashtable();`

Hashtable Key is the name of the model property and value is the actual value of the property.

E.g.

`properties.Add("STD_INCIDENTTYPEID", "myString");`

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why one should use `HashTable` instead of a Dictionary, but I'm digressing.

Given your code, I assume you have access to Json.NET.

You can convert any Json object to a `Dictionary<string, object>`, so you can:

```cs
var serializedFields = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request.Fields);
var fieldsDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();

// if you _really_ need a hashTable:
var hashTable = new HashTable(fieldsDictionary);
```

There are possibly more efficient ways, but given the optimization of Json.NET and the fact that you are guaranteed to use only serializable types, I think this is the simplest solution.